# Calendario Agenda en VB.Net?

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio, windows-forms, visual-studio-2017, calendar

Necesito hacer una vista de calendario tipo agenda en una solución de Windows Forms con VB, algo así como se muestra en las imágenes, donde pueda tener un calendario por mes, y mostrar las citas programadas en él.

[image: Vista calendario con eventos]

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

He buscado ya varios recursos en la web, y uno de los principales problemas es que ya están muy desactualizados y no son compatibles con las versiones de Visual Studio actuales.

¿Conocerán alguna herramienta o biblioteca gratuita que me pueda ayudar? Llevo ya varios días buscando y haciendo pruebas, pero no he encontrado con alguno que me sirva. (El principal problema es lo antiguo que son los ejemplos que he encontrado, principalmente de CodeProject :p )

¡Les agradezco!

Comment: winform es algo antiguo.. y todos deberian ser compatibles con lo nuevo.. que problemas tuviste? el principal problema es que esto se resuelve mucho mas simple en wpf.

Comment: Problemas principalmente en el diseñador, y en algunos casos, al cargar proyectos que incluyen, al momento de abrirlos con mi VS los "actualiza" y dejan de ser compatibles algunas funciones.